# Does there exist a SPV-client in another language than Java?

Tags: blockchain, development, bitcoinj, library, spv

The only (active) project I know that implements a full SPV client is BitcoinJ, which is written in Java.

Does somebody know if there are any SPV implementations in other languages (like C) too?

Comment: BitcoinJ is SPV? It's a full node isn't it?

Comment: @jtorba It supports both modes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bitc is a thin SPV bitcoin client. See https://github.com/bit-c/bitc . It's not very advanced yet (no HD wallets, change goes back to first address), but it's  small and self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing a BitcoinJ port for .NET (C#, Visual Basic, etc), but since I'm doing it on my free time, it's nowhere near complete.

Other way to use BitcoinJ in .NET is through IKVM (which I didn't use due to some limitations).

I don't know about other languages, but I hope this is helpful.